# How to retrieve infos about creators with sparql in wikidata

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I'm trying to retrieve infos about birth and death corresponding to paintors with this query, however I have an empty result if I uncomment birth and death infos.

```
# added before 2016-10
# Recherche de tableaux avec images
#defaultView:Table
SELECT ?paintingLabel ?date ?movementLabel ?pic ?painter ?painterLabel  
                            ?painterGenderLabel ?painterCountryLabel ?birthDateLabel ?birthPlaceLabel ?deathDateLabel ?deathPlaceLabel  
        WHERE {           
  ?painting wdt:P31 wd:Q3305213. 
  ?painting wdt:P18 ?pic.
  ?painting wdt:P571 ?date.
  ?painting wdt:P135 ?movement.
  ?painting wdt:P170 ?painter.
  ?painter  wdt:P21 ?painterGender.
  ?painter  wdt:P27 ?painterCountry.
  #?painter wdt:p569 ?birthDate.
  #?painter wdt:p19 ?birthPlace.
  #?painter wdt:p570 ?deathDate.
  #?painter wdt:p20 ?deathPlace.
          
  SERVICE wikibase:label {            # ... include the labels
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" .
    }
}

#ORDER BY DESC(?time)
LIMIT 3
```

How could I modify this query to get these informations?

Comment: `wdt:P19` (not `wdt:p19`) etc., and maybe `OPTIONAL`.

Comment: Thanks you're this was simply due to the lower case!

Comment: You might want to use OPTIONAL on some of these properties anyway. As it is you won't get results for living painters or ones with some missing information.